# Quicktime Video Panning multiple inputs problem

Tags: audio, quicktime, sound-volume

QUicktime Video Question!

How do you get the audio from multiple inputs on an Interface to blend as mono.

Im using 2 inputs connected to Audio interface.. I have the input set to take audio from my interface through mac sound preferences.

But on play back Input one ends up panned far left, and 2 Far right... I would like it to take Mono Input and merge both signals
 anyone else run into this issue and have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Quicktime Player is capable of this, but you could run it through ffmpeg afterward to change the audio to mono.

`ffmpeg -i stereo.flac -ac 1 mono.flac`

If there's video too then:

`ffmpeg -i recording.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -ac 1 mono.mp3`

`-map 0` copy every channel from the first input (the only input in this case) `-c copy` copy the same codec used for encoding for speed and to avoid quality loss, `-ac 1` set the output to only have one mono channel. (The extensions are interchangeable.)

See:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation